# I can't see my application on google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have just published my application ( 1 hour ago ) . And I can't find it anywhere I have tried the manual link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.combucalc but i get nothing.

Any ideeas? Where can I mail them ?

Comment: if the status is "published" in the developer console and the package name is correct then just wait a while. It takes some time for the update to work its way through all the servers...

Comment: Really man? There a lot of questions just on this website about this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally it will take a few hours until the app is available. For my last app it took 9 hours until it was online. It was very long, indeed... Your app will be online soon.

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to wait a few more hours in all likelihood. The process used to be faster. About a year ago I remember publishing an app and it showing in under an hour. A couple months ago I published another app and it took about 5 hours to show up.

It's also worth noting that if your app title has any punctuation marks in it (most likely a comma), you may want to try searching for the app title in quotation marks. For example, a friend recently published Run, Tweet, Run. It took over a week for a search with the query Run, Tweet, Run to come back successful. However, if you explicitly searched with quotes around the title, as in "Run, Tweet, Run" you'd get a hit.

Good luck. It'll be up in no time. And remember, Google has the fastest publishing process of all major app stores: Apple takes about a week, Amazon takes 2-4 days, Microsoft takes 3+ days. So a few hours really isn't that bad.

Answer (score 3):

It takes a little bit of time. It used to be a lot faster (instant), but lately it takes about 2-3 hours. Give it a while, it will show up.